# jQuery Slideshow - want random but need to start with same image

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, slideshow

so i found this amazing jQuery slideshow called Skitter. it's awesome! so i implemented it in my latest project.
i got it @ http://thiagosf.net/projects/jquery/skitter/#documentation

Is it possible to (and if so, how do I) have the images be randomly displayed BUT always start with a particular one?
For example, say I want the first image that it shows when a user loads the page is a particular one with a welcome message. But then for every image "after" that one, it's randomized.

I have the "show_randomly: true," part in the head and my current slide is randomizing successfully. I just hope to have a 'start' image.

So from its homepage, I did the "Customize Features" and copy/pasted the code it gave me into the head of my page...

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link type="text/css" href="scripts/SkitterSlideshow/css/skitter.styles.css"
      media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" 
      src="scripts/SkitterSlideshow/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
      src="scripts/SkitterSlideshow/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
      src="scripts/SkitterSlideshow/js/jquery.animate-colors-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
      src="scripts/SkitterSlideshow/js/jquery.skitter.min.js"></script>

<!-- Init Plugin -->
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".box_skitter_large").skitter({
                animation: "randomSmart", 
                dots: true, 
                preview: true, 
                controls_position: "center", 
                numbers_align: "right", 
                hideTools: true, 
                show_randomly: true, 
                controls: true, 
                interval: 5000,
                velocity: 0.5,
            });
        });
</script>
```

So like i said, i have a successful slideshow running and it IS randomizing the images. Just need a way to have it always start with one particular image from the list.
THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, that isn't a functionality of the Skitter script. However, you can easily add it. Start by opening up the `jquery.skitter.js` file (it will be hard to make changes to the .min.js file you're using now, and you can always minimize it later on).

Find the following line:

```
if (this.settings.show_randomly) this.settings.images_links.sort(function(a,b) {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
});
```

Immediately after that, add this:

```
/* START INITIAL FIXED IMAGE MOD */
if (this.settings.show_randomly) { /* Only use a fixed initial image if show_randomly is enabled */

    /* The following function is used to move an item in an array from fromIndex to toIndex */
    Array.prototype.move = function(fromIndex, toIndex) {
        this.splice(toIndex, 0, this.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0]);
    };

    initialIndex = 0;

    /* The following function finds the desired initial image and stores it's location */
    $.each(this.settings.images_links, function(index, item) {
        if (item[1].slice(0,9) == "[initial]") initialIndex = index;
    });

    this.settings.images_links[initialIndex][1].replace("[initial]", ""); /* Removes the [initial] tag so the link works properly */
    this.settings.images_links.move(initialIndex, 0); /* Move it to the front of the array so it's displayed first */
}
/* END INITIAL FIXED IMAGE MOD */
```

Then, to declare an initial (start) image, simply add `[initial]` to the beginning of the href attribute of the desired image. The following example will always start off with images/003.jpg, assuming you have show_randomly enabled in the script options.

```
<div class="box_skitter box_skitter_large">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#cube"><img src="images/001.jpg" class="cube" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>cube</p></div></li>
        <li><a href="#cubeRandom"><img src="images/002.jpg" class="cubeRandom" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>cubeRandom</p></div></li>
        <li><a href="[initial]#block"><img src="images/003.jpg" class="block" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>block</p></div></li>
        <li><a href="#cubeStop"><img src="images/004.jpg" class="cubeStop" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>cubeStop</p></div></li>
        <li><a href="#cubeHide"><img src="images/005.jpg" class="cubeHide" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>cubeHide</p></div></li>
        <li><a href="#cubeSize"><img src="images/006.jpg" class="cubeSize" /></a><div class="label_text"><p>cubeSize</p></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to minimize this again, there are several Internet services, such as http://www.minifyjavascript.com, http://refresh-sf.com/yui, or http://jscompress.com.

Comment: HOLY AWESOME BATMAN!!! Dude, you rock. Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you!!! i'm always amazed & astonished at the good will the people on this site have. i can't wait to try this (tonight). i'm speechless at your kindness.