# JQuery Slider randomize specific slides

Tags: jquery, random, slider

I need to the 1st slot and the 5th slot image to always remain the same. Then slots 2nd, 3rd and 4th to have 3 images rotate for each slot.

5 Slots and 11 images:

1. image1 only
2. image2, image 3, imag4 (one of these three images will show randomly)
3. image5, image 6, imag7 (one of these three images will show randomly)
4. image8, image 9, imag10 (one of these three images will show randomly)
5. image11 only

This came close to what I need but I need the last image as well to stay the same and not randomize:
[jQuery Slideshow - want random but need to start with same image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945992/jquery-slideshow-want-random-but-need-to-start-with-same-image)

I just don't know how to make the fifth slot last.

Comment: Are you also using the Skitter plugin?